# Blank screen during the execution of a java application on the swing frame

Tags: java

I have the following three classes:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

 public class Racquet {
   int x = 0;
   int xa = 0;
   private Game game;


   public Racquet(Game game) {
    this.game= game;
}

   public void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth()-60)
        x = x + xa;
}

   public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, 330, 60, 10);
}

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
}

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        xa = -1;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = 1;
}
```

}

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Ball {
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   int xa = 1;
   int ya = 1;
   private Game game;

   public Ball(Game game) {
    this.game= game;
}

void move() {
    if (x + xa < 0)
        xa = 1;
    if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - 30)
        xa = -1;
    if (y + ya < 0)
        ya = 1;
    if (y + ya > game.getHeight() - 30)
        ya = -1;

    x = x + xa;
    y = y + ya;
}

   public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
}
```

}

```
      import java.awt.*;
      import javax.swing.*;
      import java.awt.event.*;
       public class Game extends JPanel {

       Ball ball = new Ball(this);
       Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);

        public Game() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            racquet.keyReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            racquet.keyPressed(e);
        }
    });
    setFocusable(true);
}

    private void move() {
    ball.move();
    racquet.move();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    ball.paint(g2d);
    racquet.paint(g2d);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        for(long i=0;i<=100000*100;i++)
        {
         }

    }
}
```

}

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  class T extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public T()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        JButton b1=new JButton("Click me");
        b1.setBounds(150,150,50,50);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        add(b1);
}
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
{
        Game ob=new Game();
        ob.main(null);
}
      public static void main(String args[])
{
      T obj=new T();
}
```

}

When I execute the class **T**, I am supposed to get the Game but I don't know  why I get the blank screen and not the game. I am new to Java so could someone help me out?

Comment: And use a Swing Timer to drive your animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the T class doesn't work is that your code uses bad code to run the game loop, a `while (true)` loop that if called on the Swing event thread (as T does), will completely block the this thread, preventing it from performing its necessary functions including drawing the GUI.

The solution is to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive your game loop, not a `while (true)` loop. To gain a better understanding of Swing threading issues, please read: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)